# Why does magento need so much time to update a css change?

Tags: magento-1.9, rwd

I always have to waits some minutes to see changes after I edited my css file. What can causes this and how can I fix this? Thank you.

Edit: I disabled all caches and I always refresh browser cache.

Comment: press Ctrl + F5  also you webserver apache or nginx caching files too?

Answer (score 2):

There can be various reasons for this:

- Disable/flush Magento caches
- Disable/flush Browser caches
- In case of any (reverse) proxies between you and the shop, also Varnish, for example, there can some extra caching that needs to be updated

Answer (score 1):

For minutes you mean changes rendered in frontend or you mean you have to perform many refresh pages to see those changes?

when you perform changes in CSS you must disable all the area of cache management. additionally in folder var/cache you will find all the folders that are maintaining those files. you can delete all content inside cache folder and you will see those changes faster.

for more information please provide more details in your question. brgds

Comment: Yes I disabled all caches and I tried to delete the folder in var/cache but still it needs some time to make the changes visible on the site.

Comment: try to install a "clear cache" extension for firefox or chrome. probably the browser is using its own cache.